# Plain ordered list keystrokes do not work properly

Tags: org-mode, keystrokes

The keystrokes `M-<up>`, `M-<down>`, `M-RET` etc. do not work as described in the manual in an ordered list, but they change all the plain list into an unordered list. What could have happened?

- Emacs v26.3
- Org mode version 9.1.9 release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542
- iMac 2015 OS X El Capitan

Comment: What does `C-h c M-<up>` say? Similarly for the others.

Comment: M-up say _runs the command org-metaup_ and similar for the others: _org-metadown; org-meta-return_

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with emacs-28.2, org-9.6.1 on debian-11.

Comment: FWIW, like @FranBurstall, I cannot reproduce it: I tried a bleeding edge version of Org on a bleeding edge version of Emacs, but also Org 9.5.5 on Emacs 28.2 and also Org mode 9.1.9 on Emacs 28.2. It all works according to the docs in all these versions. Try restarting Emacs with the `-q` option (which will avoid loading your init file) and see if it still the case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I solved the mystery. My ordered list was part of an unordered list. This work correctly:

- item  zero

  - item one

    1. alpha
    2. beta
    3. gamma
    4. delta

but this does not:

- item  zero

  - item one

  1. alpha
  2. beta
  3. gamma
  4. delta